# Facebook API PHP :: Error posting picture along with status

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Here is my function for posting to Facebook:

```
require 'facebook-src/facebook.php';
function Facebook($content,$link=false,$image=false,$caption=false)
{
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => 'myappid',
 'secret' => 'mysecret'
));
$token='mytoken';

$post = array('access_token' => $token,'message' =>$content);
if ($link!==false) $post['link']=$link;
if ($image!==false) $post['picture']=$image;
if ($caption!==false) $post['caption']=$caption;

try{
$res = $facebook->api('/MyPage/feed','POST',$post);
} catch (Exception $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

This works perfectly at posting to my page wall, except when there is an image to be posted.

I've tried giving the image as:
`http://www.mysite.com/full_link_to_image.png`

And I've also tried
`/home/local/path/to/image.png`

To the former Facebook replies: `(#1500) The url you supplied is invalid`

And to the latter Facebook replies: `(#100) picture URL is not properly formatted`

I can't figure out why the problem is. My image is at that location and it is a good image. The resolution of the image doesn't seem to be the problem. Facebook gives the same error with any image I attempt to add, and if there is no image then it posts fine without an error.

Comment: _"except when there is an image to be posted."_ Do you want to upload a photo to your feed?

Comment: @AdamAzad, I'm trying to post a normal status update, but which includes an image.

Comment: Posting photos isn't counted as **status update**, Do you want something like 
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151759895453951

Comment: I just want a thumbnail image to go alongside my post... I've found I can do it by changing `link` to the image URL and then inserting the link URL into the content. But this is messy and it links out to an image file, which is not what I want.

Comment: Thumbnails are only available when posting links, not for status updates.

Answer (score 0):

First, please make sure that you aren't working from localhost and that http://www.mysite.com/full_link_to_image.png works in browser.

You need to use /photos it will upload the photo to your albums AND publish it on your wall along with whatever message you specified. But you cannot get a side thumbnail that way.

```
$attachements = array(
    'access_token' => 'PAGE_TOKEN',
    'title' => 'POST_TITLE',
    'message' => 'MY_MESSAGE',
    'url' => 'IMAGE_URL';
);                                                                          
$result = $facebook->api('/PAGE_ID/photos', 'POST', $attachements);
```

To get a thumbnail you have to use a link

```
$attachements = array(
    'access_token' => 'PAGE_TOKEN',
    'title' => 'POST_TITLE',
    'link' => 'LINK_URL',
    'picture' => 'IMAGE_URL'
    'description' => 'LINK DESCRIPTION',
);

$result = $facebook->api('/PAGE_ID/feed', 'POST', $attachements);
```

Depending on your image dimensions the thumbnail will be either on the left side or on top of the link.

Test it with another website's image if it still doesn't work.